# How to change/restructure an already fixed format of a data table?

Tags: r, formatting, data.table

I get always a data table of this format:

```
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 365),
                 Germany = rnorm(365, 2, 1), check.names = FALSE)
```

The data table `dt` is only a counterexample. Every day of a month has a value (price), but it is also possible that a day has an NA-value.

**...** can be understood as any value.

What I want to do is, to change the format of this data table into the following form (colors can be ignored):

[image]

The first column defines the months of the year and all other columns are declaring the dates, e.g. price on the 2nd Jan is 2.11 or on the 31th Sept is 1.78. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract month and date in separate column and get the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
  mutate(month = format(date, '%b'), 
         date = format(date, '%d')) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = Germany)
```

If you want to do this in `data.table` you can use `dcast`.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(dt[,`:=`(month = format(date, '%b'), date = format(date, '%d'))], 
               month~date, value.var = 'Germany')
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. If I use the first approach with ```dplyr``` package and define it as a new data table ```dt.test```, I get the following error message: **Error in exists(what, where, inherits = FALSE) invalid first argument**

Comment: Are you using the same data? Seems like an issue with the environment. Can you restart R and try again?

Comment: Now it's working. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to solve it using `data.table`.
Note that `month.abb` is a built-in variable in `r`.
Using `factor` function and `month.abb` as levels allows to sort the months properly.

```
library(data.table)

dcast(dt[, month := factor(months(date, abbr = TRUE), month.abb)], 
      month ~ mday(date), value.var = 'Germany')

 #    month     1     2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11    12 ...
 # 1:   Jan  1.44  1.77 3.56 2.07 2.13 3.72 2.46 0.73 1.31 1.55 3.22  2.36
 # 2:   Feb  1.70  2.90 2.88 2.82 2.69 2.55 1.94 1.69 1.62 1.31 1.79  0.73
 # 3:   Mar  2.38  1.50 1.67 0.98 0.93 2.30 2.45 2.05 2.92 4.05 1.51 -0.31
 # ...
```